# Why are the PrintPreview and PrintOut Preview:=True methods sending directly to the printer instead of previewing?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm cobbling together a macro to deal with an enormous amount of paperwork. It's designed (and copied and pasted from online examples) to essentially enable a mail merge entirely within excel, using one sheet as the form letter and another as the database.

I've tried a few different variations on object.PrintOut Preview:=True, object.PrintPreview, etc. and I can't get a print preview window. It sends right to the printer.  Similarly, I can't get the PrintToFile parameter to do anything either.  The preview range is set to TRUE in the worksheet, and I've even tried explicitly setting it to True in the code, with no change.

```
  If Range("Preview") Then
    'Neither of these options appear to work in Excel for Mac. It sends directly to the printer.
    'ActiveSheet.Printout Preview:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintPreview
  Else
    If Range("PrintPDF") Then
      'This also doesn't appear to work in Excel for Mac. Also sends directly to the printer.
       ActiveSheet.PrintOut PrintToFile:=True
    Else
      ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    End If
  End If
```

I expect to be able to get a print preview message, and when using the PrintToFile parameter, I expect to get a dialog box asking for a file name, per the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use

ActiveSheet.PrintOut PrintToFile:=True
 ' This is for the current printers command files

the only solution is

ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF